# How to make service in flutter

Tags: flutter

I want to know how to create service in flutter that service work in background of app.Any example about that.I researched but it but couldn't find a solution to do. for android and ios

Comment: Take a look at https://pub.dev/packages/background_fetch and https://pub.dev/packages/foreground_service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem to solve in one of my projects.
Unfortunately, Flutter does not provide any way to implement always-on service.
Moreover, iOS does not allow anything like this unless you are running some predefined services like Music Player.

So we can implement this natively as follows(with some limitations on iOS):

**Android:**

I implemented Foreground Service in Android. https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services#StartingAService

Then, I used MethodChannels to start and stop the service from Flutter.
https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels

**iOS:**

Only specific background tasks are allowed on iOS. Check below:

[image]

More here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/app_and_environment/scenes/preparing_your_ui_to_run_in_the_background/updating_your_app_with_background_app_refresh

Comment: Hello brother .. Ok, this is what happens on Android, but what about ios? how we can solution that?i want to send notification by thia way